# redirect .htaccess xml file to php not work on subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I like to use this code to redirect all xml to php
but it not working on  subdomain.domain.com

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^category.xml$ sitemap.php [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?filename=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean? Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: Does `subdomain.domain.com` have same DOCUMENT_ROOT as `domain.com`?